# SQL Query to return row with latest date for each scheduled step number and job number

Tags: sql

I have a dataset from a manufacturing resource planning (MRP) software which includes scheduling data. This scheduling data is provided for each individual Job in the system. Each job can have several "Steps" of the same process type (CNC, for example). Each Step can have several entries broken up across multiple days, depending on the length of the job. I am trying to create a simplified schedule that essentially just tells the supervisor of each department when the job is due from THEIR department. I can specify the department through the GUI of the MRP software. The below dataset link is a Google Sheet preview of the raw results when searching the Scheduling Table using "CNC" as the department, ordered by JobNo, StepNo then EndDate.

**Raw Data**

| JobNo | StepNo | DeptNo | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20935-77 | 50 | CNC | 3/8/2023 13:48 |
| 21036-07 | 30 | CNC | 4/18/2023 16:30 |
| 21036-07 | 30 | CNC | 4/19/2023 10:56 |
| 21036-07 | 40 | CNC | 4/19/2023 14:52 |
| 21036-07 | 50 | CNC | 4/20/2023 7:41 |
| 21036-07 | 60 | CNC | 5/2/2023 16:30 |
| 21036-07 | 60 | CNC | 5/3/2023 12:36 |
| 21036-07 | 100 | CNC | 5/4/2023 11:52 |

I have two potential goals. The first, and probably simplest, is to simply get the JobNo, StepNo, DeptNo and EndDate for the LAST "CNC" step for each JobNo. This will be an acceptable solution 95% of the time. See "Desired Result #1" in the Google Sheet. If this is all I can accomplish due to complexity, then that is fine!

**Desired Result #1**

| JobNo | StepNo | DeptNo | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20935-77 | 50 | CNC | 3/8/2023 13:48 |
| 21036-07 | 100 | CNC | 5/4/2023 11:52 |

The alternative, which would be the best solution, involves getting the same result but with the added caveat that any time there is a "break" in the step numbers it should give the result of each "block" of CNC steps. See "Desired Result #2" in the Google Sheet. This is because there are times when a part goes through the CNC department then goes to another department for other work, then returns to CNC for finishing. I would like the Supervisors to be able to differentiate those initial steps from the subsequent finishing steps later on so they can schedule them separately.

**Desired Result #2**

| JobNo | StepNo | DeptNo | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20935-77 | 50 | CNC | 3/8/2023 13:48 |
| 21036-07 | 60 | CNC | 5/3/2023 12:36 |
| 21036-07 | 100 | CNC | 5/4/2023 11:52 |

A little more info for clarity:
The reason I only need the date from the last consecutive CNC StepNo is because all consecutive steps are done consecutively in the shop. They each contain their own instructions elsewhere in the table which describe the work to be done. I only want the supervisor in that department to know when their scope of work needs to be completed in order for the final product to ship on time.

I don't have specific Queries to show what I have tried, unfortunately. I have tried using all manner of MAX(), TOP 1(), GROUP BY and ORDER BY statements with several nested Queries to try to pare the data down to just what I want but I simply can't figure out how to get the info I need.

Comment: Whenever you use the word "consecutive" when describing how to map source data to what you need for a result set, you need to be thinking **gaps and islands**. That's the key search phrase that should help you build the kind of query you need.

Comment: Also please don’t link to any external sites. Your question needs to be self-contained so please update your question with 1) sample source data 2) the result you want to achieve 3) the SQL you’ve managed to wrote so far. All as editable text appropriately formatted

Comment: NickW: Post edited to correct formatting. Joel: I'll start looking into the "gaps and islands" approach

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query using partition for

Desired Result #1

```
SELECT JobNo, stepno, deptNo, enddate
FROM (
    SELECT JobNo, stepno, deptNo, enddate,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobNo
                          ORDER BY enddate desc)
                    AS row_number

    FROM jobs
) sub
WHERE row_number = 1
```